# Right style menu by right clicking

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

Goal:
Have a right click menu with a right style

Problem:
How should i retrieve this style when I'm right clicking:

[image: Request to retreive this style]

and not this style:
[image: Current style that I would like to remove]

I'm using the component ContextMenuStrip to display menu by right clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using *ContextMenuStrip*, you have to use **[ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx)**. This is from MSDN:

> Although ContextMenuStrip replaces and adds functionality to the ContextMenu control of previous versions, ContextMenu is retained for both backward compatibility and future use if you choose.

I've tested it with a primitive example and it does work as you want. Please note, that using *ContextMenu* you lose some designer functionality and you have to manually set some properties in your code file.

In my example I changed *ContextMenuStrip* to *ContextMenu* type, all *ToolStripItem* objects to *MenuItem*, bound the menu to form's *ContextMenu* property and removed all size settings (*ContextMenu* does not use any).

Comment: Thanks for you help...
Gonna need another help from your side, once you have right click menu on the screen and you clicked h one of the option, what event, method or something similiar do I need to enter to the next process. I know what how to to do related to Contextmenustrip thanks by component but this situation is different.

Comment: @FullmetalBoy: Each MenuItem object has Click event. Here you can find an example how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.click.aspx